# Создание пачки фалов с неправильной нумерацией

Tags: файлы, bash, циклы

Как можно создать пачку файлов с нумерацией заполняя слева нуля до ширины максимального значения индекса. Если правильно поняла по заданию то по типу `file000`, `file100` и так далее

Как по простому цикл понимаю как написать

```
for i in file{000..999}

do 
  touch "$i"
done
```

Но тогда будет созданы файлы с нумерацией по типу `file001`, `file002`

Comment: Нет, заполнение слева нулями - это как раз формат `file001`

Comment: Что мешает озвучить само задание, а не приводить свои догадки? Ко всему прочему чтобы создать нумерованные файлы вовсе не нужно использовать цикл, достаточно, например, такой команды ```touch $(paste -d '.' <(printf "%s\n" file{00001..10}))```.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам поможет:

```
touch ./file{001..999}
```

Этого должно быть достаточно, чтобы выполнить то, что от Вас реально требуется. Ну а если делать так, как Вы спросили то:

```
while read -r num;do
    file_num="${num}000000"
    touch ./"file${file_num::3}"
done < <(seq 999)
```

Вот еще вариант

```
printf 'file%.3s\n' {1..999}"000" | xargs touch ./
```

Еще один, и хорош )))

```
for i in file{1..999}000;do
    touch ./{i::7}
done
```

> Но МВо, ИМХО, прав   Поскольку при такой нумерации у вас получаться
>   как минимум по 2 раза сгенерить `file100, file110, file120 ... file200 ... file900`
>   и так далее